# R - how to turn time stamp into minutes?

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I have a column containing a bunch of timestamps such as 2:03:45, which represent 2 hours, 3 minutes and 45 seconds (not 2:03PM). I'm wondering how I can go about turning 2:03:45 into a minute value, which would be 123 + 45/60 minutes.

I have used `strsplit(x$time, ":")` so that now it is separated. Is there a way I can run a for loop through the rows, so that it takes the hour * 60 + minutes + seconds/60? Thanks.

Comment: @dbenham Dave, can getTimestamp do this simply? I'd be interested to see the syntax if it can.  It occurs to me now that the OP may need a bash solution.

Answer (score 1):

install the chron package

```
 install.packages("chron")
```

load the library

```
  library(chron)
```

Ill create a timestamp character string to play with

```
d=c("2:20:34","3:12:22")
```

read the data into a date-time class

```
df=strptime(d,format='%H:%M:%S')

> minutes(df)
[1] 20 12
> hours(df)
[1] 2 3
> seconds(df)
[1] 34 22
```

so all we need to do is compute the minutes from these three

```
   timeinminutes= 60*hours(df)+minutes(df)+seconds(df)/60
```